# Getting: WARNING: Module.symvers is missing. when trying to build nvme driver module in v6.5

Tags: drivers, kernel, nvme

I have cloned the source code for (v6.5) and I am trying to build just nvme driver module and I am using the following command:

```
sudo make M=drivers/nvme
```

But it is giving me the following error:

```
MODPOST drivers/nvme/Module.symvers
WARNING: Module.symvers is missing.
     Modules may not have dependencies or modversions.
     You may get many unresolved symbol errors.
     You can set KBUILD_MODPOST_WARN=1 to turn errors into warning
     if you want to proceed at your own risk.
ERROR: modpost: "try_module_get" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "misc_deregister" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "__num_online_cpus" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "snprintf" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "class_destroy" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "scnprintf" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "kfree" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "fortify_panic" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "__fentry__" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "__x86_indirect_thunk_rax" [drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: suppressed 927 unresolved symbol warnings because there were too many)
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:144: drivers/nvme/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/home/machineName/LinuxKernelCode/linux-6.5/Makefile:1984: modpost] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
```

How to resolve this issue?
I have tried installing headers and also, I have enabled NVM Express block device support in the .config file.

The version of my linux kernel is: 6.5.0-25-generic.

Comment: Please change the image to a copy/paste of the text. Text can be copied en can be searched, with images you can not.

Comment: does this help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24760/10017 2 methodes provided there: do a `make modules` or a `touch Modules.symvers` (where it probably needs to be `sudo touch /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers`  Last one suppresses the warning. I would be more concerned with the errors ;)

Comment: by doing touch Modules.symvers I am getting this:
 make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'drivers/nvme/host/nvme-fabrics.ko', needed                                                                                                                                                              by '__modfinal'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [/home/sandisk/LinuxKernelCode/linux-6.5/Makefile:1952: modules] Er                                                                                                                                                             ror 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make]